# FInding the pdf and cdf of a negative value?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference, cumulative-distribution-functions

I hope you are doing well.

The only thing I really understand is that I am trying to find the 'weight' probability of random variable x on this function of Y. I do not know if, because it is negative, I should treat it differently than the usual way I would go about it.

Thanks ahead of time.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eg1OY.png)

Comment: The function $f(x) = -\sqrt{x}$ is injective (one-to-one) from $(0,1)$ to $(-1, 0)$, so the usual "change of variables" approach will work just fine. The sign of the function values does not really change things.

Comment: If you could answer the questions for $Z=\sqrt{X}$ then going to $Y=-Z$ should be easy: $f_Y(y)=f_Z(-y)$ and $F_Y(y)=1-F_Z(-y)$